# How to clear NSUserDefaults Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

When I choose a language from language selection list in my app then it shows that language which I selected previously. If I clear the app from my simulator stack or clear it from xcode then run the project, after that it goes ok, and if I want to change the language again then I faced same problem. My code is given below:

```
- (IBAction)English:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[userDefault synchronize];

ChooseItemVC *civc = (ChooseItemVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseItemVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:civc animated:YES];
}
```

Another language selection code:

```
- (IBAction)Arabic:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[userDefault synchronize];

ChooseItemVC *civc = (ChooseItemVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseItemVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:civc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "clear the app" ? because when you close the app and again run the app, preference is still there.

Comment: I don't understand as well, do you want to delete the whole UserDefaults dictionary (all keys + all values)? a specific value? a specific key? a specific key + value?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to remove all user default vlaues are as follows :
Swift code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)

UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Objective C

```
NSString *strIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:strIdentifier];;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Calls to `synchronize` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to remove all existing data in user defaults, i am posting swift code, convert this to objective-c.

```
  if let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundleID)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove you data from `NSUserDefaults`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove use this

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: you can use `removeObjectForKey` because he wants to remove single one. not all.

Comment: Calls to `synchronize` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

For remove data from NSUserDefaults Try this:

```
        NSString *AppDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:AppDomain];
```